# What is the correct term if a technical device is not within its working limit?

Tags: terminology

If you have a device, e.g. sensor, which currently is in a state, in which it does not work (e.g. speed too high), what would be the correct term to express that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various words that might apply, depending on the device and context concerned.

They include **stopped** (for a clock or similar), **out of order**, **faulty**, **defective**, **inoperable** and **broken**.

There are also expressions such as **playing up** (for an intermittent fault), **on the blink** and **out of commission** (for a device that has been withdrawn from service).

Comment: running too fast, for the example given, too.

Answer (score 1):

If the sensor is not broken, but is being asked to measure something that it wasn't designed to measure, you might say "out of range of the sensor".

> The voltmeter has a range of 0-100V. If you go out of range you may damage the delicate components inside the sensor.